# When using Spark structured streaming , how to just get the aggregation result of current batch, like Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

One big different between Spark Structure Streaming (SSS) and Spark Streaming (SS) is SSS can leverage statestore. It can store aggregation result of previous batches and apply current result with previous result. So it can get the real aggregation result from the very beginning of the input stream.

But for one case, we don't want to get the final result that merged with previous value of statestore. We just want to get (ouput) the aggregation result of current batch. And duo to the platform&framework thing, we can't rollback to SS.

So my question is, is it still doable in SSS to get the aggretation result of current batch, like SS?

Taking word count application for example which is given in the spark structure streaming guide:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html

When there is a "`cat cat`" comes in one batch, my expected output is `cat|2`.

And when "`cat`" comes in next batch, my expected output is `cat|1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it still doable in SSS to get the aggretation result of current
>   batch, like SS?

One way to achieve what you want is to control the state store yourself using `mapGroupsWithState`, and use it as a kind of degenerate store that actually doesn't do anything. For example:

```
val spark =
  SparkSession.builder().appName("bla").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val socketDF = spark.readStream
  .format("socket")
  .option("host", "127.0.0.1")
  .option("port", 9999)
  .load()

socketDF
  .as[String]
  .map { str =>
    val Array(key, value) = str.split(';')
    (key, value)
  }
  .groupByKey { case (key, _) => key }
  .mapGroupsWithState((str: String,
                       tuples: Iterator[(String, String)],
                       value: GroupState[Int]) => {
    (str, tuples.size)
  })
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
  .format("console")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Assuming I have a stream of values in the format of `key;value`, this will just use `mapGroupsWithState` as a pass through store and not actually accumulate any results. That way, for each batch, you get a clean state with no previously aggregated data.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark 2.4 there seems to be an easier way to achieve this, which is using the

> foreachBatch

operation, as you can read in Spark documentation.

However, I am using 2.3 version of Spark and have not managed to solve this problem.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could provide an example of how you solved this challenge of using SSS as if it was the older SS API.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Append output mode ?

> Append Mode - Only the new rows appended in the Result Table since the last trigger will be written to the external storage. This is applicable only on the queries where existing rows in the Result Table are not expected to change.

Comment: Append Mode will return the whole result, not the aggregation result for each batch. So in this case, with watermark to be set, append mode will output only one record after watermark, that would be cat|3 and only cat|3.

Comment: If a new cat event comes after the threshold and 3 cat events were received before it, we would have batch 1 : cat|3 and batch 2 : cat|1. 

> However, the partial counts are not updated to the Result Table and not written to sink. The engine waits for “10 mins” for late date to be counted, then drops intermediate state of a window < watermark, and appends the final counts to the Result Table/sink.

from the append mode example : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking

Comment: Yes that would work but with a longger latency (watermark is the latency). Actually it is a clean solution for this. But it added a limitation that user have to choose between latency and watermark. So if user needs less latency but bigger watermark setting, this will fail the users.